# pydoc export to html file from interpreter

Tags: python

`pydoc -w <module>`
works great from the command line but the environment needs to be set so that `<module>` is available. I often use python from a DCC interpreter (ie Maya, Houdini etc) where a complex hierarchy of modules is already in sys.path and it would be very useful for me to be able to export a html file directly from the interpreter instead of the command line. I assume it's possible but I can't find any docs of exactly how this can be achieved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question

```
import pydoc, os

# might be useful to set the current directory to the directory
# we want the html file to be saved. ie os.chdir('/where/to/save')

pydoc.writedoc("modulename")
```